# ImportError: No module named stdio, any way to start fresh with python?

Tags: python

I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ghs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stdio
ImportError: No module named stdio
```

When I try to run my script. I can run my script on other machines just fine. I have installed python using homebrew. And I've tried everything I can think of to get it to recognize my modules! I've uninstalled and reinstalled using brew. I've tried changing the path (though I don't fully understand this). I get no issues using brew doctor.

I've also tried using a python virtual environment but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue or else 'start fresh' from a fresh version of python?

Comment: Can you post more of your code please?

Comment: As per my understanding there is no python module stdio, so probably it is custom module written by you. If yes, then please install this module using setup.py or make sure that you have stdio module in your working directory

Comment: You're right! My C++ background got in the way. No need for stdio, strange that it was working on my other machine, thank you!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When you import a module, Python looks for it at the directory your code is, and the directory in which the built-in libraries are (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib in my case, I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.5). If it can't find it, it raises ImportError.

I couldn't find a module named stdio in my computer. I also know some C++ and as far as I know, stdio is the library for inputs and outputs(prints). In python, there is no need to import such a library.

You can use try,except statement to test if your code works without importing the module like this.

```
try:
    import stdio
except:
    #rest of your code goes here
```

You will need to indent your whole code however this can be done easily with a text editor in which you can edit more than one line at a time.

Comment: Your last paragraph is completely wrong. *Every* module is imported as `import modulename`, **not** `import modulename.py`. Additionally, putting your entire codebase under an `except` statement is very poor style.

Comment: You are right that I didn't need `stdio`. That fixed the problem. Strangely it was working on another identical computer while including the `import stdio` line. Thank you!

Comment: @MattDMo I actually wasn't so sure about that paragraph, i will edit it now. Thanks for the correction. The try, except statement suggestion was to make it clear that the program can run without importing stdio

Comment: @TevonClarenceStrand-Brown Can you please mark the answer accepted because doing so will remove this question from unanswered questions